# Using EF pre-generated views causes rebuild of unmodified projects

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have Visual Studio with more then 70 C# projects in solution. Most of them a dependent on a project where I have DB model created by Entity Framework 4.3.

I decided to create pre-generated views to increase performance as it described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

After some time I found out that any small change in project (dependent on DB project) causes rebuild of most of projects. After removing pre-build event everything returns to the normal.

Example:

Project DB - have pre-build trigger

Project A - depends on Project DB

Project B

Project C - depends on Project D

Project D - depends on Project DB

Change in Project A fires pre-build trigger on project DB and all projects except Project B will be rebuilded.

It is strange behavior because msdn for pre-buid event says:

> Pre-build events do not run if the project is up to date and no build is triggered.

[link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx)

Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: You write "any small change" which means that you actually CHANGE something. And changes always trigger the depedant projects to be rebuilt.

Comment: What is the reason to rebuild dependent project if nothing was changed in it?

Comment: You seem to suggest that the pre-build event trigger the builds. So what happens in these events?

Comment: @GertArnold I've added an example in post.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself.  You say "any small change" and then you say "nothing changed".  Did it change or didn't it change?  If it didn't change, why are you saying small changes?

Comment: @MystereMan Any small change in project (in example Project A) which is dependent on DB project causes DB project pre-build event been fired which causes rebuild of all projects.